# How to import/add multiple images as per JSON key value in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs

i am trying to add multiple images as per the JSON key value from JSON data

{"name":"abbreviation"}->
{"Alabama": "AL",
"Alaska": "AK",
"Arizona": "AZ",
"Arkansas": "AR",
"California": "CA",
"Colorado": "CO",...}

I have images downloaded and name like 'al.png' , 'ak.png' , 'az.png' which as per value of JSON format . How do I set each image for particular Card Component that I have created

````
    import  "./card.styles.css"

export const Card =(props)=>(
    <div className="card-container">
    <h1>{props.states.name}
       I am trying to add images here



     
 </h1></div>)"

This is how I am fetching all states name onto Card-list component-

componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://worldpopulationreview.com/static/states/abbr-name-list.json").
    then((response) => response.json())
    .then(users=>this.setState({states:users}));

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
      <CardList states={this.state.states}>
      </CardList>
        
      </div>```
````

Comment: Where are these images located?

Answer (score 0):

if you have those images in `public` folder then your card components should like this:

```
export const Card =(props)=>(
  <div className="card-container">
  <h1>{props.states.name}
     <img src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/images/${props.states.abbreviation.toLowerCase()}.png`} />
  </h1>
</div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to give the individual cards their data?

If I am right, in your CardList component,

```
users.map((user) => <Card><h1>{user.name}</h1><img src={user.image}</img></Card>
```